# v-model not working with javascript functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model, vue-sfc

I am new to Vue JS and have been learning it from the documentation provided. My project is a simple task adding web-app. On using the v-model directive, I'm not getting any output. My javascript function to add the task is apparently not being called.

```html
<template>
  <div id="text">
       TASKS:
      <form onsubmit="return addTodo()">
        <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="What's up" v-model="message">
        <input type="date" class="todo-input" v-model="ddate" >
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
      </form>
<div v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="todo.id" class="todo-item">
          <div>
              {{todo.id}}{{todo.title}}{{todo.date}}
            </div>
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'todo-list', 
  data () { 
    return {
      message: '',
      ddate: '',
      idForTodo: 1,
      todos: [
          
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
      addTodo(){
        if(this.message.trim().length == 0){
          return
        }
          this.todos.push({
              id: this.idForTodo,
              title: this.message,
              completed: false,
              editing: false,
              date: this.ddate,
          })
          this.ddate = ''
          this.message = ''
          this.idForTodo++
      },
      
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) You have no `ddate` data property, you should add one. 2) Your event handler should be bound using `@submit.prevent="addTodo"` or `v-on:submit.prevent="addTodo"`. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: Hi Phil. Made changes (check the edited question), the submit button still doesn't lead to an output. It just reverts to the input form back again.

Comment: Why did you move the event handler from your `<form>` to your submit button? Buttons don't emit a _submit_ event, only forms do

Comment: yeah, you can use onSubmit for form, or onClick for button (but then it will not work if user submits form from keyboard)

Comment: @MaximMazurok I always prefer _submit_ on the form for exactly that reason. Seems it's often overlooked

Comment: I added v-on:click.prevent="addTodo" in the button tag and it works now. Is adding onSubmit in the form tag an alternative?

Comment: @RajAryanSharma yes and a better one in my opinion (see above regarding keyboard form submit). Just to clarify, in Vue it's `v-on:submit` or the short version `@submit`. React uses `onSubmit`, `onClick`, etc

Comment: Alright understood. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like someone edited the question with correct code while I was writing the answer. I tried and tested same code in code snippet and it's working.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#text',
  data() {
    return {
      message: '',
      ddate: '',
      idForTodo: 1,
      todos: [
          
      ]
    }
  },
    methods: {
      addTodo(){
        console.log(this.message)
        if(this.message.trim().length == 0){
          return
        }
        this.todos.push({
          id: this.idForTodo,
          title: this.message,
          completed: false,
          editing: false,
          date: this.ddate,
        })
        this.ddate = ''
        this.message = ''
        this.idForTodo++
      }   
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="text">
  TASKS:
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="todo-input" placeholder="What's up" v-model="message">
    <input type="date" class="todo-input" v-model="ddate" >
    <button v-on:click.prevent="addTodo">Add</button>
  </form>
  <div v-for="(todo, index) in todos" :key="todo.id" class="todo-item">
    <div>
      {{todo.id}} {{todo.title}} {{todo.date}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I edited it back to the original (incorrect code). My bad.